# Receive notification when third-party access to Google account is revoked?

Tags: google-oauth, google-account

When using federated login with Google in an app, that app requests access to your Google account. It's then possible to revoke that access by following [these steps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?hl=en#:%7E:text=Remove%20third%2Dparty%20account%20access).

Is it possible to get notified (for instance via a webhook; like for "[Sign in with Apple](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/?lang=en#/dev217f824b6)") if a user revokes the access?